# Is it acceptable to leave out implementing some details of a problem solution?

Tags: discussion, answers

I provided a partial solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760391/distribute-a-number-to-total-number-of-days-in-a-month-randomly/23760954) which shows a possible approach to the problem posed. The OP doesn't find the answer very satisfactory because I haven't written out a complete solution. Rather, I've addressed what I think is the core problem, but the code I've written has some rough edges, which I've noted in the answer. The OP asks me to create a complete working solution, but I'm not really inclined to do that. Is an answer of the type I gave for that question acceptable?

Comment: Chances are that you'll be asked to write another project even if you were to supply the working code.  Such users don't expect an explanation, but a working code.  Move on.

Comment: It is very obvious that the OP of that question wants someone to write their code for them. You've done well with it, move on.

Comment: Seems fine to me. If people want to be able to demand code written to a spec, they can pay a consultant.

Comment: Nice answer, the OP is clearly asking for way too much here.

Comment: all of the above ...

Comment: It is perfectly legit, and, in fact, preferred, to give a partial (but coherent) answer that addresses and elucidates the OP's problem(s) without providing a complete solution.  Anyone who doesn't appreciate such answers should be seeking help on Facebook, not SO.  However, where there are non-obvious (to the OP) "gotachas", limitations, or edge cases those should probably be identified, to the extent that you're able, but need not be fully addressed.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

"Acceptable" in what sense?

There's no SO rule that says you cannot post a partial answer.

The person who asked the question may find it unacceptable and so are the people who will read your answer. They can downvote your answer if they wish. There's no rule against this.

There's "partial" in the sense that you have a 90% solution the explains the salient issues but does not deal with edge cases, and then there's "partial" in the sense of having a one-liner that merely sends the OP in the right direction but explains nothing. The second case is more likely to get a cold reception.

There's also the issue that if you post a partial answer, someone else can come and post a complete one on the basis of your partial answer. So long as they give proper attribution, doing this is not against the rules.

Comment: There's also the case when you use "..." instead of obvious code if you get the feeling the OP is capable of filling in the blanks by himself. It will make the OP happy but on the long run might not be enough for other people stumbling on the same problem. Then again, people stumbling on the same problems usually have comparable skills, so this might not be such a big issue.

Answer (score 34):

You're free to post as complete or incomplete of an answer as you want.  If the community finds your answer useful, they will upvote it, if they find it not useful, they will downvote it.

There are no official site guidelines with respect to how complete an answer should be.  The community sets its own guidelines through votes.

Answer (score 7):

Your answer should result in a reasonable OP knowing what to do to solve his problem.  Whether you achieve this by including implementation details or not is not important.

If your answer leaves out implementation details, it's fine, as long it's reasonable to assume that it will lead the OP to a solution.

If the OP can do the extra work to do the extra work to implement your answer, but just doesn't want to, It's not your fault.  Your answer can still help future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

This is a question-and-answer site, not a problem-and-solution site.  If a question cannot be answered other than by a complete working solution, it really doesn't belong on this site.  So provided you answer the question, a posting without a complete listing is fine.

Just be careful though to make sure that any code that you *do* post compiles and runs correctly.  Otherwise, I will find it and downvote it.

Comment: I think it is unfair to expect posted code to compile/run without error.  Eg, I often answer Objective-C questions while working on my Windows laptop and have no way to test compile them.  Anyone making an answer should attempt to post valid code (except when obviously posting pseudocode), and should correct typos in the code if they're identified, but expecting perfection is unreasonable.

Comment: Then I guess I must be unreasonable! :-)

Comment: @HotLicks, you can use gcc under Windows, as long as you don't need any Mac-specific stuff.

Comment: Yes, it is quite unreasonable to expect someone to spend an extra 15 minutes of their time setting up a test environment to verify that a 10-line example is totally typo-free.  Especially when the OP likely didn't spend that much time trying to figure out the problem before posting.

Comment: Right, @HotLicks, but balance that against the needs of future users.  When I use Stack Overflow to find a solution to a problem, I don't want a broken solution - I want one that works.  If you can't take the time to make sure your solution works, then it's probably best not to bother posting it.  If I'm going to post code to Stack Overflow, I _always_ write it in Eclipse and run it, then copy-paste it to Stack Overflow.  This adds a few seconds on to the time it takes, not 15 minutes.  And if it's related to an environment that I'm not set up to run, then I don't post code.  Very simple.

Comment: Again, that's not always practical.  When it's a simple Java program, eg, I'll usually test it, if it's more than a few lines.  But I can do that in under 5 minutes.  And, as I said, if some problem is recognized by myself or others I'll correct it.

Comment: @HotLicks I think you and I are going to have to agree to disagree on this issue.  I want Stack Overflow to provide me with quality solutions to my problems.  I think that's more important than protecting the egos of those who post.  Therefore, I will continue to downvote "broken" solutions, as well as posting suggestions for improvement in the cases where it's useful to do so.  Note that whenever I downvote an answer, I always continue watching the question for a while, so that I can remove the downvote if the answer gets fixed.

Comment: I like good quality answers (not necessarily solutions) too, but the issues preventing that go far beyond this rather trivial one.  Mostly the poor quality of questions is the thing dragging the site down.

Comment: I don't disagree.  There are other posts here on MSO dealing with that.