# How to handle answers where questioners can figure out the answers themselves?

Tags: discussion

We get a fair number of beginning-programmer questions on SO that, it seems to me, the questioner "should" be able to figure out themselves, possibly with a bit of a push or a small hint.  For example: [Printing numbers in double for loop in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917337).  I'm not necessarily talking about questions they could find the answer to with a minimal amount of research--mostly I'm thinking of questions where the questioner has enough information to come up with the answer and just needs to think a little bit.

Sometimes, people post answers to the question, taking away the OP's need to think.  I don't think this serves the beginning programmer any; they get code they need to complete their homework (probably) but are deprived of the opportunity to learn how to come up with such answers themselves.

What's the best way to handle these answers?  Downvote them?  Add a comment explaining why I think it's a bad idea to spoon-feed OP's?  Let it go on the theory that it's not my place to meddle?  Thoughts?

Comment: I'm sure this is a dup, but I'm too lazy to search for it. In most cases, such posters are of the "wham bam" variety, often have just signed up, and usually will figure out their question themselves and not even bother to come back to see someone's carefully crafted answer, much less upvote or accept it, which is punishment enough for people who choose to waste their time that way. The consensus around here, which I don't always follow, seems to be to **not** downvote answers based on whatever thing you don't like about the question.

Comment: Thanks.  I did try to search for a dup but didn't find anything.

Comment: Definitely don't bother commenting: I can't see that accomplishing anything other than an argument, especially if the answerer disagrees with you about whether the OP should be able to figure it out.

Comment: Related? [What happened to the “You're Just Lazy” close vote reason?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216491/what-happened-to-the-youre-just-lazy-close-vote-reason) [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: see also: [Should we “hand-hold” in our answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255896/839601)

Comment: To be honest, it's very difficult to draw the line to which questions can or can't be figured out by the OP themselves. If they could have solved it themselves, they would probably not have asked it in the first place. Sometimes they just need a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), and in those cases I think some answerers **are** those rubber ducks. Is it bad to answer those? I don't know, I find it very hard sometimes to put myself in the perspective of someone new to library X or Y, and things that are obvious to me, aren't always obvous to others.

Comment: I remember being a beginner. I needed the spoon feeding.

Comment: @Suragch I was there not long ago. Sometimes you just need that spoon when your brain can barely understand what's going on. As long as people learn slowly why things work, sometimes it's good to see something *working* before understanding *why* it works. IMHO

Comment: If I had 10 meaningless internet points for every problem I solved on my own by writing it out on the "ask a question" page (i.e. rubber ducking it) I'd have...10 (thousand)... meaningless internet points. Well, ok, not actually 10k, but a lot. Especially if I including when I've done it on sites other than SE.

Comment: Will auto-delete scripts delete this question automatically at some point in future? It have multiple answers, all upvoted and one accepted. But the question has 14 downvotes. Are this kind of questions subject to delete automatically by some bot?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that flaggin dupes (if there are any), or at least closely related questions, and also linking to the brand new Documentation should suffice to point the OP in the right learning direction, while not being disrespectful and not assuming the OP has the knowledge to work a solution on their own.

Comment: While I share much of your thoughts, there's a scenario the you've *almost* described where I don't. Consider the case of a beginner with a question that *hasn't been answered* on SO. Even IF the OP can work thing out on their own, wouldn't it be a benefit for *other* beginners to have an answer for that question?

Comment: BTW this question appears to be a duplicate of [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276963/answering-questions-give-solution-or-point-them-in-the-right-direction).  I'm not voting to close this one because I don't feel that it has been fully answered by the other question.  (That other question is marked as a duplicate of an earlier question, but it's not really a duplicate IMO.)  I have also made a new [proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351802/long-term-proposal-add-new-hint-answer-type) for discussion.  (I expect it to be rejected!  Sigh.)

Answer (score 7):

I think that with a minimal effort you can figure out the answer to this question by yourself!!! :-)))))))))))))

Answer (score 3):

Even if everyone agreed here (which won't happen, but if...) that such questions and answers should be down-voted, that likely would not change a lot since the vote system is specifically open to interpretation: ie: "vote your way".

I have seen questions where the best answer would be a LetMeGoogleThatForYou link, but last I knew those were banned on SO - something I found out when trying to post a LMGTFY link. And since SO advertises itself as the "No discussion, no fuss, just pure Q&A: ask a question, receive an answer" site, it seems that the situation you describe is partially encouraged.

That combined with the difficulty in determining if the questioner deserves the help or not leaves us in a poor place to answer your question with an affirmative.

I often put a lot of thought, research and effort into my questions, which do not receive many up-votes and occasionally some down-votes too, so it annoys me when I see people ask questions which are answered by the first hit of practically any attempted Google query. By comparison then, I feel like answering "Yes, by SO standards those should be down-voted." However, for the previously mentioned reasons I would personally err on the side of caution and not down-vote the question unless it is especially poor quality.

Comment: "_answered by the first hit of practically any attempted Google query_" Then again, the first hit for Google queries will likely quickly become that very same SO question ;)

Comment: In the linked question (in the above question), the *best* responses are in the comments on the questions.  These are the ones that give the questioner hints rather than showing her/him how to do it.  There really ought to be a way to give points to "teaching answers" (other than comment points, which don't really count).  In cases like that one, they are much more valuable than the actual "answer" answers.  I wouldn't downvote the latter, but I would upvote the suggestions in the comments in a heartbeat,if they were "answers".  However, answers of that kind are considered bad answers.

Comment: @Pooks And I remember a time when the hopeful expectation of SO was that it became the first hit for everything software. I was told at the time that all questions were desired, even if they would be answered by 10 seconds of research. So I changed my outlook accordingly, but now things seem to have swung back the other way.

Comment: @Mars I agree that helpful comments which are not full answers can be more beneficial than direct answers sometimes. Unfortunately, StackExchange has shied away from that. My understanding of the general upper-level consensus is that permanent comments are undesired and that comments are subject to deletion without notice and if that causes a problem it's our fault for leaving a permanent comment; the extreme of that mentality being that if all comments site-wide suddenly disappeared at mid-night the impact should be negligible. I disagree with that preference, but I think it's majority.

Comment: @Mars And I think cases like what you are describing are one (of many) reasons why the attitude on comments is too strict on StackExchange. Some SE sites are better than others, and SO seems mostly reasonable. I have seen other SE sites, however, where any hint of comment-discussion swiftly brings a delete-all-comments (delete, not move-to-chat), even comments that were valuable.

Comment: @Pooks If the question is *already* answered by a google search, then adding one more hit for the search doesn't help anyone, as the search *already* produced the correct answer.

Comment: @Aaron No, that's strictly false.  The goal of SO is not to duplicate all of the knowledge of all of the rest of the (programming related content of the) internet here.  The goal of SO is to ensure that questions get *a* good answer, whether it's here or elsewhere.  If a question is asking something already readily accessible elsewhere, it has no business being duplicated here.  If the question doesn't have a good answer *at all*, then it's of great value here, because it's actually improving the quality of reference content available to programmers.

Comment: @Aaron Just devoting yourself to being a plagiarist and taking content from elsewhere and duplicating it here is not adding value to society.  It's not making the world a better place.  It's just trying to benefit without doing the work of actually adding value.

Comment: @Servy That's false _now_. I said myself that this has changed. I'm talking about many years ago when SO was somewhat young. I think I may even made a meta post about it (different account) back then; I can't remember for sure. Anyway, the idea *at that time* _was_ to duplicate knowledge on SO. Of course, even with a meta post the vote is merely among those who stumble on it at the right time, which is a tiny fraction of the SO community, so what I called "consensus" above may have actually been 0.01% or less. Still, I received many down-votes and was explicitly told by multiple people (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) that the idea was indeed to make SO the one-stop-shop for all answers. That did not necessarily mean plagiarizing everything; citations are important. But as several high-rep users told me at the time, the idea was to have all programming-related questions be answered, whether directly or indirectly, through a SO answer that was the top Google hit. Now, as I said, that is no longer the case, as we have many people down-voting for just the opposite and asking people to please do the search themselves.

Comment: @Servy - You said "If a question is asking something already readily accessible elsewhere, it has no business being duplicated here." Personally I agree with that *sentiment*, but it definitely does not reflect Stack Overflow policy (and never has). SO has no mechanism at all to discourage questions that could easily be answered by a quick Google search, except perhaps the snarkiness of commenters when such questions arise. And of course discretionary downvotes. The commenters even have to be a little creative with their snarkiness because we can't do LMGTFY.

Comment: @JohnY It's always been part of SO's guidelines that doing your research is important, and that it's bad for questions to not do basic research and as a result ask readily accessible information.  You are of course correct that there's no good mechanism to actually do anything about this; it's just empty words in SO's mission, so about all we can do is tell people that such content isn't appropriate here, with no means of actually enforcing it.

Comment: There is benefit to adding an answer available elsewhere on the web if it provides one of several possible answers to a question.  The SO question then serves to collect all of the good answers.  Usually no other page on the web will have done that.  Aside from the benefit of "one-stop shopping", it's good to be able to compare possible solutions side by side.

Comment: @Aaron I think what I'm feeling is that rather than being put in comments, which are subject to deletion, it would be good if hints could be given a status like that of answers.  Right now, you could put a hint in an answer, but it would be (rightfully, given the guidelines) downvoted.  Maybe there should be a new category of response called "hint" or "tip".  These could be upvoted and downvoted.  They probably should receive fewer points per vote than true answers.  Perhaps whenever someone adds a "hint" response, the text of real answers should be hidden until a user clicks on them.

Comment: @Aaron I have posted [a suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351802/long-term-proposal-add-new-hint-answer-type).

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to decide whether the question is homework or not. When I feel like it is homework I tend to provide just hints and not the complete answer to encourage OP to think about it.
But when someone posts solution to these simple questions then damage is done and you can't do anything about it that will do any good. Maybe the best will be to add information how to solve such kind of problem on your own. Because even if there is solution it is good to know how to get such solution.
Also I am missing tag homework. I tried to use it once when it was quite obvious. But it was rejected by SO.